# stdClass Object and array how to using php

Tags: php, arrays, object, stdclass

I'm trying to get the twelve ids that this structure shows:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [checkins] => stdClass Object
        (
            [count] => 12
            [items] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (

                            [venue] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [id] => 4564654646456
                                    .
                                    .
```

I do:

```
$checkins = $fsObjUnAuth->get("/users/self/checkins");
$count = $checkins ->response->checkins->count;  // so I can  get 12

 for( $i = 0; $i < $count; $i ++)
  {
      $a1[] = $checkins['items'][$i]['venue']['id'];  //two tries
      $a2[] = $checkins ->response->checkins->items->$i->venue->id;
        echo $i; echo ": ";
        echo $a1;echo"<br>";
        echo $a2;echo"<br>"
  }
```

But I get:
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in  line..

Please can someone show me how to do this?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot access object members via the array subscript operator `[]`.

You have to use the `->` operator:

```
$x = new StdClass();

$x->member = 123;
```

In your case you'll have to use a mixture, since you have an object (`$checkins`) with a member (`$items`) which is an array, which contains additional objects.

```
$a1[] = $checkins->items[$i]->venue->id;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple solution to *convert* a **stdClass Object** in array in php with function `get_object_vars`

Look at : http://php.net/manual/fr/function.get-object-vars.php

Ex :

```
debug($array);
$var = get_object_vars($array);
debug($var);
```

Or replace `debug` by `print_r`

I'm use CakePHP framework

Cdt

Answer (score 0):

change

```
$a1[] = $checkins['items'][$i]['venue']['id'];
```

changed to

```
$a1[] = $checkins->items[$i]->venue->id;
```