# How to retrive value from stdClass Object in array

Tags: php, arrays, object, stdclass

Have array like below :

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [city_id] => 2222
        [city_name] => newCity
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [city_id] => 4444
        [city_name] => oldCity
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [city_id] => 6666
        [city_name] => newCity2

    )
)
```

Now, I want get `city_id` when I set `city_name`, how can I get it in my codes?

For example, If I set `newCity2` for `city_name` then I see `6666` for `city_id` and etc.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5156841/stdclass-object-and-array-how-to-using-php?rq=1.. Perhaps this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through it as

```
foreach($data as $key=>$val){
  echo 'City ID ::'.$val->city_id."<br />";
  echo 'City Name ::'.$val->city_name."<br />";
}
```

If you want to see a particular data then you can modify above as

```
foreach($data as $key=>$val){
  if($val->city_name == 'newCity2'){
   echo 'City ID ::'.$val->city_id."<br />";
   break;
  }
}


function getCityIDByName($cityname,$data){

    $return = '';
    foreach($data as $key=>$val){
          if($val->city_name == $cityname){
           $return = $val->city_id
           break;
          }
    }
    return $return ;
}

$city_id = getCityIDByName ('newCity2',$data);
```

Comment: the value of city_name is not static, it is dynamic

Comment: well you can make a function to do so as I updated in the question.

Comment: please see my conversation with @Explosion Pills in the another answer, both answers are same but do not work for me :(

Answer (score 0):

You would have to iterate over the array and check `city_name` to get the corresponding ID.  You could also do this initially to set up an array with `city_name` as the key and `city_id` as the value.

```
foreach ($array as $value) {
    if ($value->city_name == $compareCityName) {
        $city_id = $value->city_id;
    }
}
```

Comment: I did set like you but when I want to see result then got error `Undefined variable: cityId`, my code is : `$city = 'oldCity'; foreach($results as $value){ $cityName = $value->city_name;
if ($cityName == $city) { $cityId = $value->city_id; }
} var_dump ($cityId); exit;`

Comment: @sIiiS that means that no city named `oldCity` was found

Comment: I did set before `$city = 'oldCity';` as you can see in my codes, but why can not find it?

Comment: @sIiiS because it's not there?  Depends on the contents of `$results`

Comment: value of `$results` is same as `$array` not else, and in the `$results` in my main Q, oldCity is available

Comment: @sIiiS are you sure that `$results` is defined in your code?  Did you `var_dump` it?  What does it say?

Comment: yes, sure, I set print_r for `$results` and then see array codes in my main question in the first post

Comment: @sIiiS code is working fine for me.  I copied the code from your comment and the array you posted above and it worked perfectly.  Only thing I can think of is that `oldCity` has some non-printing character or something.  Instead of comparing to the string `oldCity`, try comparing to `$results[1]->city_name`

Comment: yes, you right! when I var_dump value of `city_name` from `$results` then back me oldCity, oldCity has 7 string but it return 13 string and I don't know why!!! ... the value of `city_name` are unicode

Comment: also find that, all string return false, they back (2x(string)city_name)+1 , do you know, how can I solve it ?