# object of class stdclass could not be converted to string in php when contacing a webservice

Tags: php, web-services

I am trying to call a function in my C# webservice but get this error:

> "Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be
>   converted to string".

This is my code:

```
<?php 
try
{
    $soap_client = new
    soapclient("http://tsb01.cnap.hv.se/PersonalService/ServicePersonal.svc?wsdl");
    $quote = $soap_client->VisaPersonNamn();
    echo "$quote";        


}
catch(SoapFault $exception)
{
    echo $exception->getMessage();
}
?>
```

The webservice is really simple it only returns one string..

Can't figure out what's wrong.. help would be really nice!! :)

Comment: `VisaPersonNamn` returns an object, not a string. Use `var_dump($quote)` to see it.

Comment: Ok, thx i see the response like this:
object(stdClass)#2 (1) { ["VisaPersonNamnResult"]=> string(4) "Kurt" } 
I only what to show "Kurt", how can i do that??

Comment: @Newbie1337 please up-vote the answer too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly The problem is  `VisaPersonNamn` returns an object, and you are terating it as an string by writing `echo "$quote";` instead of it use either `var_dump($quote)` or `print_r($quote)`.

Now as you show that var_dump($quote) gives you output like below:-

```
 object(stdClass)#2 (1) { ["VisaPersonNamnResult"]=> string(4) "Kurt" }
```

To show value `Kurt`,You need to call like this:-

```
echo $quote->VisaPersonNamnResult;
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this line `echo "$quote";` to `echo $quote->VisaPersonNamnResult;` if you will always have a single record in response.

If you receive multiple records, you can iterate over each record like,

```
foreach( $quote as $record )
{
    echo $record;
}
```

More details on accessing PHP Objects [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5156841/stdclass-object-and-array-how-to-using-php)