# how can i select this item in array?

Tags: php, wordpress

Hello i made this query for wordpress plugin

```
$anyOne = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT MAX(id) as idlastest FROM " . $table_name_for_select . " WHERE drJlDate='".$dkdrbooking_for_compare."'");
```

the value in `$anyOne` is

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [idlastest] => 32 ) )
```

I need to get 32 to use it in another query, but i can't select that. How can I get `idlastest` from this array ?
I tried this code, but it didn't work

```
echo 'lastestID is : '.$myIds[0]['idlastest'];
```

Comment: try $myIds[0]->idlastest

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5156841/stdclass-object-and-array-how-to-using-php here, I hope it helps.

Comment: @Danielius tnx so much

Comment: @sozkul tnx so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an object in your array, so use `->` to get object value

```
echo 'lastestID is : '.$myIds[0]->idlastest;
```

Comment: 11.3k. don't you think it will be good to give comment rather than answer this type of question? but no offense, the green numbers shown by stack attracts every one.

Comment: @Anant If comment can describe answer, why here answer option? i really appreciate your word and thanks to show me my position

Comment: sorry need w8 for 6 min to chose this answer currect

Comment: @Anant It's only help to OP whether you give comment or answer it's your opinion. You can dislike if not agree

Comment: @Anant Thanks let's move forward

Answer (score 1):

As you want to fetch single record use get_row function instead of get_results. And if you want to get results in array instead of object you can pass argument "ARRAY_A" in function as below.

//Change in query

```
$anyOne = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT MAX(id) as idlastest FROM " . $table_name_for_select . " WHERE drJlDate='".$dkdrbooking_for_compare."'",ARRAY_A);
```

//Fetch result

```
echo 'lastestID is : '.$anyOne['idlastest'];
```

Comment: hi tnx for ur answer acutyl i need run this quary
$anyOne = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT drTurn FROM ".$table_name_for_select." WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) as lastestid from ".$table_name_for_select." WHERE drJlDate ='".$dkdrbooking_for_compare."')");

Comment: but it show me nothig and i chose write it some part

Comment: @A.imahrap Ok got it.

Comment: Yes, if you want to fetch only one record then get_row is better choice than get_results.

Comment: tnx so much Rahul , i useing get_row , and my long qury work too , 
i new in stackoverflow , for show tanx to u just can give u vote ? or i can do anythig ?

Comment: and can i use get_var too ?

Comment: Your welcome :) your vote is enough my friend.. you can accept my answer as well but you have done it already by accepting Rakesh's answer so that's ok. No problem.